# MySQL query for follow system

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a follow table with columns userid and following and I have a user table with userid and username.

I want to be able to select the users who follow say user 4 but in the same select query have a column lets call is followornot which would either be 0 if user 4 does not follow whoever is selected or 1 if user 4 follows the selected user.

I had something like this in mind but it does not work as expected.

The query is as follows

```
SELECT
  u.username,
  u.userid,
  (case when following= '4'  then 1 else 0 end) as followornot
FROM user u inner JOIN followTable f ON f.userid = u.userid
WHERE f.following = '4'
```

Sample Records:

**User**

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ USERID ║ USERNAME ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ john     ║
║      2 ║ jane     ║
║      3 ║ smith    ║
║      4 ║ paul     ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

**FollowTable**

```
╔════════╦═════════════╗
║ USERID ║ FOLLOWINGID ║
╠════════╬═════════════╣
║      1 ║           2 ║
║      4 ║           1 ║
║      3 ║           4 ║
║      1 ║           4 ║
╚════════╩═════════════╝
```

[**SQLFiddle Link**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35f55)

Comment: can you please provide a sqlfiddle with your table/data example? www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What's unexpected about the way it works? Is it that, mysteriously, you only get rows with `followornot` = 1? That would be because your `WHERE` clause limits the query results to those with `following='4'`, i.e. those with `followornot` = 1.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35f55

Comment: @nurdglaw The query is supposed to pull all users who follow user 4 but the thing is followornot should reflect if user 4 follows someone of the people who follows him.In my sqlfiddle for instance smith and john follow paul but paul only follows john so the query should output rows with john or smith but the followornot column should have 0 for smith and 1 for john. With the query that I have the followornot column is 1 for both john and smith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.*,
        (d.followingID IS NULL) followornot
FROM    user u
        INNER JOIN followTable f
            ON u.userID = f.userID
        LEFT JOIN followTable d
            ON  u.userid = d.followingID AND
                d.userID = 4
WHERE   f.followingid = 4
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35f55/12)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦══════════╦═════════════╗
║ USERID ║ USERNAME ║ FOLLOWORNOT ║
╠════════╬══════════╬═════════════╣
║      1 ║ john     ║           0 ║
║      3 ║ smith    ║           1 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do sth like this:

```
select u.id, f.key_user, key_follower FROM user u INNER JOIN is_following f ON u.id=f.key_user AND f.key_follower=4;
```

where u.id is a user-id, key_user the fk in is_following and key_follower the user_id who is followed by user-id.